# How to create Telerik MVC Combobox via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, telerik

I want to implement the ability to dynamically add comboboxes and I have to use Telerik ComboBox for that. I put this logic into button click.

```
$('#add-presenter').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var combobox = '@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("Presenters[" + (Model.Count) + "]")
            .BindTo(new SelectList(LeaderList, "ID", "Value"))
            .ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnChange("onSelect"))
            .DataBinding(bnd => bnd.Ajax().Select("_LoadJournalist", "MonitoringFRadio"))
            .Filterable(filter => filter.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.StartsWith))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px;vertical-align:middle;" }))';
        combobox = combobox.split('Presenters[' + index + ']').join('Presenters[' + (index + 1) + ']');
        index++;
        $('#presenters-block').append(combobox);
}
```

This code renders in browser as this:

```
$('#add-presenter').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var combobox = '<div class="t-widget t-combobox t-header" style="width:320px;vertical-align:middle;"><div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default"><input class="t-input" id="Presenters[0]-input" name="Presenters[0]-input" type="text" /><span class="t-select t-header"><span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">select</span></span></div><input id="Presenters[0]" name="Presenters[0]" style="display:none" type="text" /></div>';
  combobox = combobox.split('Presenters[' + index + ']').join('Presenters[' + (index + 1) + ']');
  index++;
  $('#presenters-block').append(combobox);
  combobox = $('#Presenters\\['+index+'\\]').data('tComboBox');
});
```

The problem is in data-binding. This code generates proper HTML, but newly added list doesn't "drop"
When I do `combobox = $('#Presenters\\['+index+'\\]').data('tComboBox');` for newly added item I get undefined (it exists, but `data` isn't set), so `combobox.dataBind(dataSource)` approach doesn't work.

Comment: Proper HTML isn't enough. The data binding is done trough the JavaScript API. The code generated by the HTML helpers also renders a `script` which, when run, initializes the component.

Comment: I see, but how should I do this?

Comment: I don't really understand why the helper doesn't generate the script tag in your code. Maybe you need to explicitly set `ToString()` at the end; maybe that's unrelated. I'd take a different approach and build/insert the combobox using the JavaScript API.

Comment: I've read through http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html and I still don't get how it is possible to build combobox using their API. It seems that the part I need to make this new combobox behave correctly runs on server and is not exposed anyhow. Looks like it's technically not possible to do this without postback and redrawing all comboboxes again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried, but failed to do this without postback. Here's rough solution to the problem: do ajax request and replace content with partial view:

The Partial view:

```
@model List<int>
@{
    var LeaderList = ViewData["LeaderList"] as List<ListItem>;
}
<div id="presenters-ajax-wrapper">
<div id="presenters-block">
    @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("Presenters[0]")
            .BindTo(new SelectList(LeaderList, "ID", "Value"))
            .ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnChange("onSelect"))
            .DataBinding(bnd => bnd.Ajax().Select("_LoadJournalist", "MonitoringFRadio"))
            .Filterable(filter => filter.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.StartsWith))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px;vertical-align:middle;" }))

    @for(int i=1; i<Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = LeaderList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == Model[i]);
        var value = item != null ? item.Value : "";
        @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
              .Name("Presenters[" + i + "]")
              .Value(value)
              .BindTo(new SelectList(LeaderList, "ID", "Value"))
              .ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnChange("onSelect"))
              .DataBinding(bnd => bnd.Ajax().Select("_LoadJournalist", "MonitoringFRadio"))
              .Filterable(filter => filter.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.StartsWith))
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:320px;vertical-align:middle;" }))

    }
</div>
<button id="add-presenter" class="t-button">+</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = @(Model.Count == 0 ? 0 : Model.Count-1);

    $('#add-presenter').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        index++;
        var msg = $('#monitForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_GetPresenters","MonitoringFRadio")'+'?count='+(index+1),
            data: msg,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#presenters-ajax-wrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult _GetPresenters(EditableMonitoring model, int count)
{
  //some logic here...
  return PartialView("EditorTemplates/Presenters", model.Presenters);
}
```

Well, probably it would be better to create another partial view which would render a single combobox, instead of redrawing all of them...